# Outer resolve() not called within then() clause of inner promise

Tags: node.js, promise

In the following code, calling the `resolve()` at point (A) does not result in execution of the `then()` clause of the call to `createRequest()`.  The code is getting to the point of the `resolve()` call, which I verified by the print statement.

```
const request = require('request');

function createRequest() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // Setup request
    // ...

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 201) {

        // If the resolve() is done at this point, the then() clause is executed

        uploadFiles(files)
          .then(handles => {
            console.log('handles: ' + handles); // This is printed

            resolve('ok'); // (A) Then clause in call to createRequest is not called
          })
          .catch(reject(requestObj)); // (B) I didn't have this in my initial post
      }
    });
  });
}

function uploadFiles(files) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Upload files
    // ...

    resolve(handles);
  });
}


createRequest()
  .then(message => console.log(message) /* This never executes */)
```

[edit]

I added a `catch()` clause to my `createRequest()` call, and I was surprised to see something get printed, which was strange because the `handles:` statement was getting printed.  I changed (B) to the following:

```
.catch(() => reject(requestObj));
```

and my problem was solved.  The `then()` in the call to `createRequest` was getting executed.  Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Have you maybe already called `reject()` elsewhere? Otherwise no, if you get the `handles:` log and the `resolve('ok')` is executed, then the `then` callback will also run.

Comment: I'll look at that question, but I'm not calling reject() anywhere. The ```handles:``` print should mean the ```resolve()``` is executed.

Comment: Check agian owner of `resolve` variable, maybe your `resolve` (`resolve('ok')`) not related to your promise.

Comment: @user2233706 Yes it should. When I execute your code, it works for me. Given that you omitted some things, I'll guess the culprit is elsewhere. Can you post your complete actual code, please?

Comment: Yes, I hadn't posted my complete code.

Comment: Instead of `request`, use the already (correctly) promisified `async-request`.

Comment: `.catch(reject(requestObj))` does indeed call `reject`, it's different from `.catch(() => reject(requestObj))`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because `catch()` expects a function, not a function call.  Even though the `catch()` clause is not executed, NodeJS still expects it to have a valid function.  If not, the promise is rejected by NodeJS.  For example:

```
const request = require('request');

function createRequest() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var options = {
        url: 'https://www.google.com'
    };

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {    
        uploadFiles()
          .then(handles => {
            resolve('ok');
          })
          .catch(reject('bad')); // (A)
      }
    });
  });
}

function uploadFiles() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve([1, 2, 3]);
  });
}


createRequest()
  .then(message => console.log(message))
  .catch(message => console.log(message));
```

This results in 'bad' getting printed.  If (A) is replaced with `.catch(() => reject('bad'));`, then 'ok' is printed.